# Memory Allocation in Dynamic Linked List of Structs

Tags: c, list, memory, dynamic

What's the difference in allocating memory with Malloc or Calloc in this example?
With Calloc the memory breaks, but with Malloc is fine!
My example is similar to (but with many values):
[image]

If the code is wrong, how should I do it?

```
typedef struct {
    int ID, age;
} person;

typedef struct {
    person *person;
    struct NO *next;
} NO;

...   // with calloc, the memory breaks
      // with  (NO*)malloc(sizeof(NO))  it´s fine

NO *p1, *px1, *px2;

px2 = (NO*)calloc(1, sizeof(NO));
p1 = px2;
px2->person->ID = 1; px2->person->age = 30;
px2->next = NULL;
px1 = px2;

px2 = (NO*)calloc(1, sizeof(NO));
px2->person->ID = 2; px2->person->age = 20;
px2->next = NULL;
px1->next = px2;
```

...

Comment: You never allocated px2.person. You're deferencing an uninitialized pointer. calloc fails because memory is zeroed and accessing 0 results in segfault. With malloc it's UB but you're probably writing to a random memory location.

Comment: calloc is helping you by setting person to NULL.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference in allocating memory with Malloc or Calloc in this example?

Provided that `a` and `b` are both positive and `a * b` does not overflow, the difference between `calloc(a, b)` and `malloc(a * b)` is only that `calloc` initializes the allocated memory to all-bits-zero.  Nothing else.

> With Calloc the memory breaks, but with Malloc is fine!

Your program is faulty regardless of whether you use `calloc()` or `malloc()`, whether it breaks *noisily* or not.  You allocate memory for a `NO`, but then you dereference its `person` pointer without first assigning it to point to a valid object.  The result is undefined regardless of which allocation function you use.

Comment: Obviously you're right, deferencing a null pointer (or better in this case, a pointer pointing to the address 0) is explicitly listed as UB but it was not unseen in dos programs to access the interrupt table. OK, maybe old time compilers simply didn't bother with such optimisations...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, who says a pointer whose representation is all-bits-zero is either a null pointer or a pointer to address 0?  Either of those *could* be the case, but the C language does not promise either one.

Comment: For NULL it's true but isn't assigning 0 _officially_ considered the same from C99? I never carefully read what Standard says about this then it might be only with an explicit assignment. Not sure.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti *the integer constant `0`* is a null pointer constant, and assigning that to a pointer object makes that object's value a null pointer.  But the same does not apply to assigning an integer *expression* with value 0 to a pointer, and none of that has anything to do with the bits in the representation of a pointer object.  There have been conforming C99 implementations where the representation of a null pointer is not all-bits-zero.

Comment: You're right, it's not even when 0 is represented with all zeroed bits. Considering expressions would make it extremely hard for the compiler. Thank you!